# Get directory after specific folder name in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-os

I am trying to get the rest of the directory after a specific folder. Say, for example:

/heres/some/folders/with/files

And I want everything after /folders/:

/with/files

This is what I have:

```py
Tk().withdraw()
directory = os.path.basename(filedialog.askdirectory())
print(directory)
```

I know that basename only prints the current folder, but I could not find anything on this to even try and code it.

Comment: Read up on [`os.path.split(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os%20path#os.path.split)

Comment: This seems more like it, yet, I can't figure out how to split at a certain folder. Take the above as an example, how do I cut out everything prior to /with/?

Comment: `"/home/user/with/test".index("/with/")` gives you the start index. Then `<your string>[index:]`

Comment: Right, however:
```python
Tk().withdraw()
directory = os.path.dirname(filedialog.askdirectory())
print(directory.index("/materials/"))

print(directory[91])
```
Only prints "/"

Comment: Should read `print(directory[91:])`. Read up on [Tutorial - 5. Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures)

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry. Thank you.

That answered it then.

Comment: So are you trying to find the string `/folders/` as a substring of the full directory name and then print the rest of the string? If so, what do you want to do if it exists more than once?

Comment: I don't want to print it. I need everything after, including /folders/ (/folders/with/files) to insert into a file.
If it exists more than once, well, I don't expect this to happen given what I want to do.